# Independent Nested Loops in PHP

Tags: php

Say i have two different arrays. I want to get each value from the first array, and add to it some values of each key in the second array. How do i do this please?

I tried using a foreach loop inside a foreach loop and for each value in the first array, it appends each value of the second array which isn't what i want

```
$array1 = array(chris, kate, john, jane);
$array2 = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 2, 'third' => 3, 'fourth' => 4);

foreach($array1 as $name){
   foreach($array2 as $k => $v){
      echo $name . "-" . $v;
   }
}
```

I want my output to look like this

```
chris-1
kate-2
john-3
jane-4
```

Sometimes, the count of both array aren't the same. Some values in the first array produces an empty string, so in cases like that, it should just skip the value. Once the empty string in array1 is skipped or deleted, the count then matches array2

My above nested loop can't give me this. How do i go about this please?

Comment: Do those 2 arrays always have the same length?

Comment: @catcon They don't

Comment: @Nick i have adjusted the question. Will it still work?

Comment: So what is the expected result if the first array is longer than the second one?

Comment: No. But what should happen when the arrays have different lengths? Can you edit the question to show that as well?

Comment: Sometimes, some values in the first produces an empty string, so in cases like that, it should just skip the value. Once the empty strings in array1 is skipped or deleted, the count then matches array2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would use [array_filter()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the empty strings from `$array1`:

```
$array1 = array(chris, kate, john, jane);
$array1 = array_filter($array1, function($value) { 
    return $value !== ''; 
});
```

Now we need to reindex the array to account for the gaps we made when removing empty strings.

```
$array1 = array_values($array1);
```

Considering you don't use the 'first', 'second', etc keys in `$array2` for anything, we can just get rid of them using [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). This will leave us with an array like `array(1,2,3,4)` which will make accessing the data later on a little easier.

```
$array2 = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 2, 'third' => 3, 'fourth' => 4);
$array2 = array_values($array2);
```

Now we can loop through the first array and access the same position in the second array to create the final string.

```
// Assign the current element's numeric position to the $i variable on each iteration.
foreach($array1 as $i => $name){
    echo $name . "-" . $array2[$i];
}
```

## Final Code

```
$array1 = ['chris', 'kate', '', 'john', 'jane'];
$array1 = array_filter($array1, function ($value) {
    return $value !== '';
});

$array1 = array_values($array1);

$array2 = ['first' => 1, 'second' => 2, 'third' => 3, 'fourth' => 4];
$array2 = array_values($array2);

foreach ($array1 as $i => $name) {
    echo $name . "-" . $array2[$i];
}
```